# need another session in my local login

Tags: php, html, mysql

```
<?php
// Establishing Connection with Server by passing server_name, user_id and password as a parameter
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "abc", " ");
// Selecting Database
$db = mysql_select_db("run", $connection);
session_start();// Starting Session
// Storing Session
$user_check=$_SESSION['login_user'];
// SQL Query To Fetch Complete Information Of User
$ses_sql=mysql_query("select username from user where username='$user_check'", $connection );
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($ses_sql);
$login_session =$row['username'];
if(!isset($login_session)){
mysql_close($connection); // Closing Connection
header('Location: index.php'); // Redirecting To Home Page
}
?>
```

i want to add another session here name is tele_id. but when ii am trying to ad it, it is redirecting failed every time. what to do. can i ad it here or can i use it with two session here???

Comment: Please clear your question

Comment: your $user_check var is empty, and please dont use mysql_* functions, it's unsafe and depricated. Try mysqli or PDO.

Comment: i need to store of session, one username, and one in tele_id like "welcome, X(90)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$user=$_POST["user"];//username from html form
$pwd=$_POST["pwd"];//password  from html form


// Connect to the database
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
// Make sure we connected succesfully
if(! $con)
{
    die('Connection Failed'.mysql_error());
}

// Select the database to use
mysql_select_db("db_name",$con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT user_name, password FROM admin where user_name='$user'"); //Query to retrive data from database and check with entered data 
$result1 =mysql_query("select tele_id from user where username='$user_check'", $connection ); //Query to retrive data from database and check with entered data

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1);
$tele_id=row1["tele_id"];
if($row["user_name"]==$user && $row["password"]==$pwd)
    {
    echo"You are a validated user.";
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['login_user'] = $user;
    $_SESSION['tele_id'] = $tele_id;

    header( "Location: AdminHome.php" );
    }
else
    echo "<script language=\"JavaScript\">\n";
echo "alert('Username or Password was incorrect!');\n";
echo "window.location='AdminLogin.php'";
echo "</script>";

?>
```

Comment: In next admin page check for session values you will definitely get all the $_SESSION values...

Answer (score 0):

The $_SESSION super global can be user as an array. To store multiple variables in it use:

```
$_SESSION['login_user'] = your_value;
$_SESSION['tele_id'] = your_value;
```

Comment: do i need to add [
`$ses_sql=mysql_query("select tele_id from user where username='$user_check'", $connection );`]